# How to link to a wordpress installation's latest articles from a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress

I am creating a rails app and would like to incorporate a wordpress blog with it.

I have one area of my app that has recent stories. I would like to have it link to my blog and whenever I add a new story on my blog, the story will appear on my site in the area.

Are there any wordpress plugins that do that already, or would it be hard to create something like that since wordpress is PHP and the site is ruby on rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a Wordpress plugin in a rails application as-is, but you can certainly have a section of your website that will be generated by Wordpress instead of rails. [This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20110806004432/http://codelikezell.com/deploying-wordpress-with-rails-on-passenger/) will help you with that.

To show the latest articles from the blog, you could fetch the RSS feed of the wordpress installation and display it in your rails application. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214590/parsing-atom-rss-in-ruby-rails) will be a good start if you're going this way.